# SSRS: How to format string to money or percent when the string is itself part of string concatenation

Tags: vb.net, ssrs-2008-r2

I've 2 fields, **IncreasePct** and **IncreaseDollars** with values, such as `5.32` and `9752`. I'd like to format the cell so that I get something like this:

```
5.32%($9,165.00)
```

I've tried something like this:

```
= IIF(Fields!IncreasePct.Value = "", "", 
   Fields!IncreasePct.Value & "%(" & Format(Fields!IncreaseDollars.Value, "CO") & ")")
```

Unfortunately, my function displayed this: `5.32%(CO)`. Adding `=` is causing an error.

Any way to format those values?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

I'll do it in this way : create two different placeholder and get desired formatted value into them and placed them near to each other.